# Adding magic numbers/file header back to a zip

Tags: files, zip, manjaro

As part of a program I am in, I have been given a zip file that won't open. I have worked out that the file header is missing from the zip, but I am not sure how to put it back. Simply replacing the first bytes or using programs that ignore the header to unzip doesn't work, so I think I need to put them before the rest of the file. This might require offsetting the file or something, but I don't know a lot about hex editing/hex editors, or how to do what I need to.

I'm using Manjaro (a vm provided by the program), and gHex to view and edit the files (though I can install different ones/work from the terminal if that will solve my problem).

Edit: Running zip -F or zip -FF returns:

```
Fix archive (-F) - assume mostly intact archive
Zip entry offsets appear off by -4 bytes - correcting...
copying: masterkey
zip warning: reading archive fseek: Invalid argument
zip warning: bad - skipping: masterkey
zip warning: zip file empty
```

The problem with the above is that I am almost certain that the zip file cannot be empty -- it should contain something that has a flag (attempting to extract the 'fixed' zip also returns 'Error extracting archive' from the archive manager).

Comment: what is the result of command `file corrupted_archive`?

Comment: "Zip archive data"

Comment: It could not be a tar. Please add the output of file xxx.zip to the question

Answer (score 1):

You can try to recover the broken archive by executing command:

```
zip -F corrupted_archive.zip
```

Of you  can make `zip` to try harder to recover via

```
zip -FF corrupted_archive.zip
```

For me this is much safer and better than try to edit directly the file

Comment: Updated original question to show results

Comment: @karot, seems like your zip file is seriously corrupted. And I have my doubts if any hand operation can help

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is possible that I cannot recover this file, though I don't see why the creators of the challenge will have made it so. I will continue to look for answers